# Custom warnings in Eclipse for forgetting a method?

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings

Whenever I'm writing an Android app and making a Toast, I tend to call Toast.makeText() but then forget to call show() and get mad at myself later. Since there is no reason I would ever call Toast.makeText() and not mean to call show(), is there a way I can make Eclipse show a warning if I do that? Thanks

for clarity: I want Eclipse to show a warning anytime I call "Toast.makeText(blah, blah, blah)" instead of calling "Toast.makeText(blah, blah, blah).show()".

Comment: it should already warn you if you dont call show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

Lint warnings can do lots of handy things - page through them and see what suits you!

Comment: I believe that answers OP's question. However, I am wondering if there is any way to create custom warnings? For example I want a custom warning to be displayed if I do display more than 3 buttons/ activity. Would that be possible?